# The meaning of 'gig' here

Tags: word-meaning

> As if living on a different planet, students complain that the cost of
>   tuition — averaging $6,500 a year in 2016-17 — is so high that it may
>   never pay off, especially in the **gig economy**, where jobs are
>   precarious.

[Yes, post-secondary education makes you rich, but that may not be the best part](http://www.cbc.ca/news/business/education-canada-economics-1.4268921)

What does the '**gig economy**' mean? I looked up a few dictionaries for the word 'gig' before I posted this question but couldn't wrap my head around it when it came with the word 'economy.'

Comment: It is not a standard collocation. The noun **gig** is used attributively with **economy** to mean "an economy characterized by gigs" or where the typical job is a gig, that is, an economy where jobs tend to be short-term and project-oriented, rather than jobs where the holder enters onto a career path within a large organization and can expect to progress upward within the organization.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo   Okay, I've got it. I looked up a few dictionaries for the word 'gig' before I posted this question but couldn't wrap my head around it when it came with the word 'economy.' Thank you.

Comment: You should include what research you did when you post your question so that the folks answering it know what you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Gig economy" is, as Tᴚoɯɐuo explains in his comment, a job market characterized by *gigs* rather than steady, long-term employment.

> **[Gig](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gig)** (n): A job, especially one that is temporary or that has an uncertain future.

The phrase is most often used by musicians and similar performing artists whose income often depends on how many *gigs* they can *line up*.  The author of your quote suggests this kind of practice has become common for young people in *any* job, making their income variable and uncertain, and making it difficult to pay off their student loans.